# modelform field name can't be localized when in production

Tags: django, localization, django-forms

I have a model:

```
class Server(models.Model):
     serverId = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("serverId"))
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_("server_name"))
     ip = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_("ip"))
     cport = models.IntegerField(default=5000, verbose_name=_("cport"))
     aport = models.IntegerField(default=1000, verbose_name=_("aport"))
     hport = models.IntegerField(default=2000, verbose_name=_("hport"))
     version = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("version"))
     serverGroup = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True,
             verbose_name=_('server_group'))
     class Meta:
         db_table = u'server'

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

and the modelform:

```
class ServerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Server
```

from within this app directory I did

```
$ mkdir locale
$ django-admin.py makemessages -l zh_CN
```

then I provided the translation in locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
then I did

```
$ django-admin.py compilemessages
```

then I ran the development server:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

and went to look at the url http://127.0.0.1:8000 in firefox and the translation displayed. So I thought I did right and I deployed the project on the same machine using nginx + fastcgi with nothing changed in the whole project. Then I go to the url http://127.0.0.1, and then the the modelform shows English there. It didn't localize to Chinese.

I've googled much and read many docs from docs.djangoproject.com and still don't know how to solve the problem. So I ask here.

I only set LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh_CN' in my settings.py and leave everything on deafult. My django version is 1.2.4

Any of your comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you are using lazy_translation. Are you importing `ugettext_lazy` or `ugettext`?

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation

Comment: I use ugettext...when I switch to ugettext_lazy, it works thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

For information, django takes the first argument as the verbose name of a field.

So you can also write your models in a shorter way, like this :

```
version = models.CharField(_("version"), max_length=100)
serverGroup = models.ForeignKey(_('server_group'), Group, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

On version 1.4 it works only (for me) with ugettext not with ugettext_lazy